# Parallax-like texture depth in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, displacement

I have a texture that I want to give an actual depth. However, I dont want to use Displacement because it requires very high polygon count to work properly and it slows down render times which is quite annoying.

I know there is a method of doing this called "**Parallax Mapping**" and is used in some video games but I cant find a way of doing this in Blender.

I've put an example to show you what I want to achieve:

[image: 2D example texture on a simple plane with low polygons]
This is a 2D texture on a 2D plane that has only 4 vertices.

[image: Depth Illusion I want to achive without increasing polygon count]
This is the result I want to achieve without increasing the polygon count.

***(To demonstrate the second image, I simply used the Array-Modifier and set the offset to 1 mm and the count to 1000! Obviously, this wont work on curved meshes, slows down the performance in the viewport and it has some side effects if you look from the side...)***

[image: Side effect of the Array Modifier]

Looks like a hologram with vertical sync issues, lol

Comment: Maybe OSL is a way to go? Martin Geupel has ported an Open GL example by Joey de Vries to an OSL shader, which can be found [here](http://www.racoon-artworks.de/?p=773). I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Might be useful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture

Comment: Is [this Q&A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/107927/2217) helpful?