# Parallax occlusion portal effect

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

I'd like to create a parallax occlusion effect (cycles or eevee) where a cube or plane appears to contain another universe inside of it. I've seen a lot of brilliant solutions that can fake it using 2D images, but I'm wondering if there is a solution that would allow for objects within the plane to actual "pop out", like below --

[image: portal into another universe]

These solutions all work well for 2D planes, and I know a lot of people use this to create fake rooms inside buildings, but again you're stuck using flat images that can't cross the border of the plane. I also think anything to with compositing nodes would make the effect I'm going for impossible.

- https://twitter.com/Magryllia/status/1129566134024396800
- [Portal effect in EEVEE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137679/portal-effect-in-eevee)
- [How to make a holographic reticle shader in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107927/how-to-make-a-holographic-reticle-shader-in-cycles/107938))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way si to build both worlds inside one scene.
And then fake an 'infinitely deep' wall between them.

[image]

1. Build one set (I used an HDRI)
2. Add a wall with a 'portal' cutout.
3. Add a texture to this wall (I used stars) and use *Texture Coordinate node > Window* to map it.
   The texture will always be facing towards you, faking an infinitely deep space.

Since both worlds are *actually inside* one scene, you can freely move objects between them.

*I'm not rotating the portal, I'm moving the camera.*
[image]

Comment: Super easy and elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: And thank you, for asking interesting questions :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: Ha :) what a nice illusion!

Comment: @vklidu Thanks, been kinda proud of it then :))